# iOS: using grid Table View using BeeFramework on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I am pretty new in objective c.I want to display Multiple columns Table on storyboard .I got code for Multiple columns Table from this [link](http://code4app.net/ios/Multiple-columns-Table/51e4dd116803fa1026000000) that is using bee framework to display data.I want to integrate it with my storyboard project.I have placed all code file of Multiple Column Table into my storyboard project and then i linked StakeholderViewController stroyboard on custom class with CatelogBoard class.On executing project on that StakeholderViewController it is giving black screen giving error with execution details :

```
Unknown class GridTableViewCell in Interface Builder file
```

How i can display that on storyboard.I am using story board project from this tutorial [How to Use SQLite to Manage Data in iOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) with [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/SQLite3DBSample.zip) . You can download my attempt from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfzcs2vn4r6cjwj/SQLite3DBSample-master.zip?dl=0) .

Answer (score 1):

Take  look at using UICollectionView.  It's Apple's answer to the grid table.